# Union of Sample space

Tags: probability

Let $P(A) = 0.2$, $P(B) = 0.5$, and $P(C) = 0.3$.

What is the value of $P(\Omega ∪ B)$?

I thought this would be $0.5$, since the sample space is 0 but that is an incorrect assumption. What am I missing?

Comment: Its the whole sample space so its becomes $P(\Omega)=1$. If you are using the "or" rule then $P(\Omega\text{ and B})=P(B)=.5$.

Comment: Ok. I guess I got the definition of a sample space wrong. So the sample space would include A and C, correct?

Comment: It would yes. Since the sample space definition contains all possible events include the empty set and the sample space itself.

Answer (score 1):

$P(\Omega \cup B) = P(\Omega) = 1$

$P(\Omega \cap B) = P(B) = 0.5$